# If $x+y+z \geq xyz$ Prove that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq xyz$.

Tags: inequality

$x,y,z \in \mathbb R$

**My attempt:**

Notice that if $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq xyz$ and $x+y+z \geq xyz$. So :
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq x+y+z $$
But this is actually not always true, take the case when $ 0<x,y,z <1$ And you will see that this is not working.

Maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1519155p9065362, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h97520p550688

Comment: *Hint.* $(xy+yz+zx)^2\geqslant 3xyz(x+y+z)\iff (xy-yz)^2+(zx-xy)^2+(yz-zx)^2\geqslant 0$

Comment: Where should i use this inequality?

Comment: Further question: If $x, y, z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x+y+z \ge xyz > 0$, then what is the largest $k$ such that $x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge k xyz$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we prove for all positive $x,y,z$.

If all of $x,y,z\geq1$ we have
$$x^2\geq x ,\\ y^2\geq y \\ z^2\geq z$$ $$⇒x^2+y^2+z^2\geq x+y+z \geq xyz\\$$

If at least one of $x,y,z$ is less than $1$ then take (WLOG) $x\geq y\geq z>0$ & $1>z>0$

$$\frac{x}{y}\geq1 $$

$$⇒\frac{x}{yz}\geq1 $$
$$⇒\frac{x}{yz}+\frac{y}{xz}+\frac{z}{xy}\geq 1$$
$$⇒x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xyz$$

If two of $x,y,z$ is negative (say $x$ and $y$)
we have $$-x-y+z ≥ x+y+z ≥xyz=(-x)(-y)z$$
$$⇒-x-y+z ≥(-x)(-y)z$$ Here $-x,-y,z$ are positive numbers. So from the earlier result we can say,
$$(-x)^2+(-y)^2+z^2\geq (-x)(-y)z$$ $$⇒x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xyz$$

The inequality is obvious when one of $x,y,z$ is $0$ or if one of $x,y,z$ is negative or if all of $x,y,z$ is negative.

Comment: you said either $\frac{x}{y}\geq1 $ or $\frac{y}{x}\geq1 $ is true; then why did you use both inequalities in :$$\frac{x}{yz}+\frac{y}{xz}+\frac{z}{xy}\geq 1$$

Comment: @yassir I realised it now. No need to use both inequality

Comment: You forgot the case when two of $x,y,z$ are negative and one is positive.

Comment: Yeah you’re right, i think that @Asher Ambraham’s method won’t works in this case

Comment: @Andreas I have included that case in the post now.

Comment: $$(-x)^2+(-y)^2+z^2\geq (-x)(-y)z$$ this inequality works only if $x,y,x \geq 1$??

Comment: @yassir I proved $x^2+y^2+z^2≥xyz$ if $x,y,z$ is positive(not just for $x,y,z \geq 1$.) Therefore $(-x)^2+(-y)^2+z^2\geq (-x)(-y)z$ if x and y are negative.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you guys are too fast and / or assume too much prior knowledge. Let's digest it.

We need to be careful since all numbers are reals. Hence AM-GM and square root  methods don't work.

First, note that if $xyz < 0$, then there is nothing to prove, since in this case $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \geq 0 \geq xyz$ holds in all cases. So we need to consider  $xyz \ge  0$ only.

We want to establish the following train of inequalities:
$$
(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 \ge (xy+yz+zx)^2 \ge {3xyz(x+y+z)} \ge  {3}  (xyz)^2 = 3 |xyz|^2
$$
The first one follows from
$$
 x^2+y^2+z^2 - ( xy+yz+zx)  = \frac12 \Big[ (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+ (z-x)^2 \Big] \ge 0
$$
The second one follows from
$$
(xy+yz+zx)^2 -  3xyz(x+y+z) =  \frac12 \Big[(xy-yz)^2+(zx-xy)^2+(yz-zx)^2 \Big] \ge 0 
$$
For the third one, for $xyz > 0$, then this follows from the question's condition: $x + y+ z \ge xyz$.

So indeed it holds for all reals:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge \sqrt{3} |xyz| \ge \sqrt{3} \cdot xyz 
$$

This is also the tightest inequality, since we observe that equality holds for the question's condition and for this solution at $x=y=z = \sqrt{3}$. (River Li asked for that constant $k = \sqrt{3}$).

Comment: It is a nice solution. (+1)